# PDF Compare Python for Automation Testing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

“We are attempting to automate PDF comparison to eliminate manual efforts. I need to create a test suite for comparing PDFs.

I tried converting the PDF to HTML and using the Selenium WebDriver for PDF testing, but it failed. I also attempted to compare the text extracted from the PDF, but that approach was unsuccessful. Another option I’m considering is creating an AI model, although it would require a significant amount of time.

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?”

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.